# Having trouble adding up the output of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add all the elements within an array and print them out. This array is created from parsing through other arrays and making a selection based on specific criteria.
The final answer I get is no where close to mathematical accuracy and I'm wondering why I'm getting this result. I would like to also know how to do this correctly. 
I appreciate any suggestion that is given, as I haven't been able to find an answer specific to what I am asking - the questions and answers I found here are often very complex compared to what I am searching. Thanks.

** source arrays to be parsed...

```
$cities =  array('New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston',
                        'Philadelphia', 'Phoenix','San Antonio', 'San Diego',
                        'Dallas','San Jose');
$states = array('NY', 'CA', 'IL','TX','PA','AZ','TX','CA','TX','CA');

$population = array('8,175,133','3,792,621','2,695,598','2,100,263',
                            '1,526,006','1,445,632','1,327,407','1,307,402',
                            '1,197,816','945,942');
```

** my code to parse data, output to an array, add content of final array...

```
$p = 0;

for($i = 0, $theCity = count($cities);$i<$theCity; $i++){
   $cityPlace = $cities[$i];
   $province = $states[$i];
   $number = $population[$i];

   if($province === 'CA' ){
      $pops[$p] = $number;
      $p++;
      print "$number<br>"; //to check outcome
   }

}

$a = array_sum($pops);
print $a;
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to count? Total keys or values, or sum of numeric values?

Comment: So 1) what number do you get. 2) What number are you expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the population array numbers contain commas.

PHP being loosly typed does not care until you come to use `3,792,621` as a numeric, like adding them up, then it has to convert text to a numeric and in this process it stops when it see's the first non numeric character i.e. a `,`

So all you have to do is remove the commas like this

```
$cities =  array('New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston',
                        'Philadelphia', 'Phoenix','San Antonio', 'San Diego',
                        'Dallas','San Jose');
$states = array('NY', 'CA', 'IL','TX','PA','AZ','TX','CA','TX','CA');

$population = array('8,175,133','3,792,621','2,695,598','2,100,263',
                            '1,526,006','1,445,632','1,327,407','1,307,402',
                            '1,197,816','945,942');


$p = 0;

for($i = 0, $theCity = count($cities);$i<$theCity; $i++){
   $cityPlace = $cities[$i];
   $province = $states[$i];
   $number = $population[$i];

   if($province === 'CA' ){
        // changed line of code to remove commas
        $pops[$p] = str_replace(',','', $number);
        $p++;
        print "$number<br>"; //to check outcome
   }

}

$a = array_sum($pops);
print $a;
```

RESULT:

```
6045965
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the straightforward answer I was looking for!  I knew it had something to do with the syntax or with how I'm adding the numbers together